# variable assignment on redux saga generators/sagas

Tags: typescript, generator, redux-saga

Let's think of the following saga:

```
function* mySaga(){
  const x = yield call(getX)
}
```

In truth, the value of `const x` is not directly assigned by the return value of `call(getX())`, but rather by whatever is passed in `mySaga.next(whatever)` when it is called.

I assume that redux-saga is smart enough to manage the saga in such a way that it calls the `.next()` method with the result of the last promise yielded.

Is it, though?
How safe is it to just assume that `x` is actually the result of `getX()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How safe is it to just assume that x is actually the result of getX()

If the generator is being run by redux saga, then as long as `getX` returns something (ie, it doesn't throw and doesn't go into an infinite loop) redux saga guarantees that the saga will be resumed with that return value, and thus assigned to `x`.

If you manually step through the saga, then it will get whatever you manually insert in. About the only reason i can think for manually iterating a saga is to write a unit test, so this is not a concern you need to worry about if you're using redux saga as it was designed.